# Python, beautifulsoup scraping specific or exact numbers from a stat table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, statistics, html-table

On a [player stat page](http://www.nfl.com/player/tombrady/2504211/careerstats).

How can I make my anchor point the year "2014" and grab specific numbers in the 2014 column (scrape numbers to the right of 2014)

The code below is skipping the "Passing" table (with all of the career passing stats) and trying to grab stats from the "Rushing" table (with all of the career rushing stats), with "2014" as my anchor and scraping the next five < td > tags after "2014" (trying to scrape numbers to the right of 2014).

I believe my code is close but I'm getting an error message.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk 
from urllib import urlopen
import urllib
import re

url = 'http://www.nfl.com/player/tombrady/2504211/careerstats'
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", { "summary" : "Career Stats In Rushing For Tom Brady" })
for row in table.findAll("tr", { "td" : "2014" }):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
print cells[1]
print cells[2]
print cells[3]
print cells[4]
print cells[5]
```

This is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\jcmcdonald\Desktop\test7.py", line 17, in 
>       print cells[1](http://www.nfl.com/player/tombrady/2504211/careerstats)
>   NameError: name 'cells' is not defined

line 17 would be the first "print cells[1](http://www.nfl.com/player/tombrady/2504211/careerstats)"

Comment: `I'm getting an error message` - ok...What is it? When you ask a question, please be very specific. What is your input? What is your output? How does it differ from what you expected? Are you getting an error? If so, include the entire traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more along the lines of what you are looking for. You can't filter the year like you were trying to do, you have to have an if statement and filter it out yourself.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

url = 'http://www.nfl.com/player/tombrady/2504211/careerstats'
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", { "summary" : "Career Stats In Rushing For Tom Brady" })
rows = []
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    if '2014' in row.findNext('td'):
        for item in row.findAll("td"):
            rows.append(item.text)
print rows[6]
```

Comment: Good Solution, had to change `if '2014' in row.findNext('td'):` to `if unicode('2014') in row.findNext('td'):` in python 2.7.

Comment: And i did not run into that issue

Comment: How can I call just one of those numbers? Like the 6th number over from 2014?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk 
from urllib import urlopen
import urllib
import re

url = 'http://www.nfl.com/player/tombrady/2504211/careerstats'
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", { "summary" : "Career Stats In Rushing For Tom Brady" })
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    print row.text
```